# How do I remove entire Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

How can I get rid of Google Calendar?  I am not comfortable with my reminders on my mobile coming to my Gmail. (I am on Windows 7.)

Comment: This may be a better question for a site appropriate to your mobile phone: [windowsphone.se], [android.se], [apple.se]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

If you want to suppress the notifications from mobile, then:

Go to "Google Calendar" > "main menu" in the top left > choose 'Settings' > choose one of your calendar > Touch a notification and choose No notification > Repeat for each notification.

Note: If you have multiple accounts or calendars, repeat these steps for each calendar.

If you want to suppress the notifications from the computer, then:

Go to "Google Calendar" > choose 'Settings' > choose one of your calendar > click Edit notifications next to your calendar's name > click remove next to each notification.

Note: If you have multiple accounts or calendars, repeat these steps for each calendar.

Hope this helps.